# BasePart.Touched event only triggers when touching its sides Roblox

Tags: roblox

I have a problem that I never met before that is the `BasePart.Touched` event only fires when another `BasePart` touches it **ON THE SIDES**. Even on my existing code, I now have this problem that does not make sens. Why is the `Touched` event only fires when a `BasePart` touches its side, **not above or below**. Here's an image that describes my problem:[image: Only fired on sides]. I did not illustrate for the two other sides but you get the idea.
That's a big problem for this game + my existing games that when the `Parts` are touched, they should kill, fade, … .

I simply tried to rotate the part, still do not fixes it; I realized that it wasn't anchored, I anchored it but did not change a single thing; Tried putting another part above and below: not fixed!

How would I fix this really bad problem?

Edit: I'll answer everything in some hours.